# React router getIndexRoute does not render

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Trying to implement code splitting with react router.

> index.jsx

```
const routes = {
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    getIndexRoute(partialNextState, callback) {
        require.ensure([], function (require) {
            callback(null, {
                component: require('./home/index.jsx'),
            })
        })
    },
    childRoutes: []
}
```

> home/index.jsx

```
module.exports = {
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            cb(null, require('./components/home.jsx'))
        })
    }
}
```

> home/components/home.jsx contains

```
module.exports = Home
```

There's no compile or render errors. How does this work? Using webpack 1.13 and react router 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some refactoring, but this works:

> index.js

```
import rootRoute from './routes'
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router routes={rootRoute} history={browserHistory} onUpdate={onUpdate}/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

> routes/index.js

```
import App from './components/app'
import Home from './routes/home/components/home'


const route = {
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    indexRoute: {component: Home},
    childRoutes: [
        require('./routes/about').default,
        require('./routes/services').default
    ]
}

export default route
```

This means that my app (which nest/hold every page thereafter is loaded, and the relevant child route is loaded async:

> routes/about/index.js

```
const route = {
    path: '/about',
    getComponent(nextState, callback) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            callback(null, require('./components/about').default)
        })
    }
}

export default route
```

So when my url changes to `/about` the about chunk is loaded.